# Got black screen when recording screen from xvfb by ffmpeg x11grab device

Tags: ffmpeg, xvfb

I'm trying to record video from a firefox run by `xvfb-run` but it always output nothing in the video file except black screen.

Here's what I did:

start a firefox, open google.com:

```
$ xvfb-run firefox https://google.com
```

Then it will use the default display server number 99. I can see the display information by command `xdpyinfo -display :99`.

A screenshot works very well by command:

```
$ xwd -root -silent -display :99.0 | xwdtopnm |pnmtojpeg > screen.jpg
```

Start using ffmpeg to record a video:

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :99.0 out.mpg
```

When I play the video file `out.mpg`, there's black screen all the time.

Is there any parameter I missed?

**Updates**

I made progress that the video works instead of black screen only by this command:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -r 30 -g 300 -f x11grab -s 1024x768 -i :99 -vcodec qtrle out.mov
```

Notice it requires the screen resolution matches by specify more options to `xvfb-run`:

```
$ xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1224x768x16" -a firefox http://google.com
```

But I still want to get more feedbacks and answers here.

Comment: Black according to what player(s)? Please show the complete console output for each `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: Following [the docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab), I also added `-show_region 1` to the arguments. Still no luck. Something that stood out to me: Not even the region is shown on the display. If I run this on the main display `:0.0`, both works (I get video *and* see the region-border). If I run in on another screen (like with `vncserver`) neither works.

Answer (score 5):

I happened to have the same problem and found out:
you have to specify the depth (16 in this case) so ffmpeg won't produce the black screen.

e.g.

```
Xvnc -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 :10  <<---WORKS
Xvnc -geometry 1024x768 :10            <<---does NOT work, produce black screen.
```

Comment: ``16`` seems to be the default (according to the Xvnc4 man-page). I have the same problem and tried both ``16`` and ``24`` as depth. Still have a black video. Do you still have the command you used for ``ffmpeg``?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem (black video, while screenshots showed the frame-buffer) with the following line:

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :99.0 out.mp4
```

After not being able to find any solution I changed (out of poor desperation) the extension/encoder to "webm".
And suddenly it worked, I got the video with the actual content:

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :99.0 out.webm
```

So no idea what is going on here (broken encoder?), but maybe it's worth a try for anyone left with a black video after recording.

EDIT/PS: Turned out my problem was VLC, which could not decode x264 in hardware and ended up with a black video. "mplayer" or any other were doing fine. So the problem was not in the recording to begin with. Doh.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Seems like it had something to do with the version of ffmpeg available in the official Ubuntu packages (Kubuntu 15.04 in my case to be precise).

I downloaded the ffmpeg sources and with a bit of help of [the docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) I managed to get something running.

The build process takes a *long* time! And by default many features (x11grab among others) are disabled. I ended up with the following:

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/home/exhuma/.local \
    --enable-x11grab \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --enable-libmp3lame \
    --enable-nonfree
```

I now have both video *and* sound.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have fixed this bug but if you haven't let me help out because I ran into the same issue. Here's a solution (I'm running on Fedora 30):

Your need to Configuring `Xorg` as the default `GNOME` session. On your terminal open your `custom.conf` by typing this command:

`$ sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf`

and uncomment

`WaylandEnable=false`

if it's commented but must be set to `false`

Then, on the `[daemon]` section just under `WaylandEnable=false` add this line:

`DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop`

and save the file. Then try running your Screen Recorder program again.
Congratulations.

However, if nano command is not working please try installing it by running the command:

`$ sudo dnf install nano`

or

`$ sudo apt-get install nano`

whichever works for you.

Comment: you need to relogin also

Comment: What does this have to do with the question, which is about recording Xvfb?

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue on ubuntu 22. Had to enable xorg on login screen to fix it:

[image]